# Register defaultHandler and batchHandler both in HttpConfiguration.MapODataServiceRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to enable 2 features in service i.e 
**defaultHandler: new ODataNullValueMessageHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) })**

and

**batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));**

How can I register both in MapODataServiceRoute()?
I think we can register one at a time. if I register both separately, It override last one.

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                   routeName: routeName,
                   routePrefix: routePrefix,
                   model: GetModel(),
                   defaultHandler: new ODataNullValueMessageHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) });

config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                   routeName: routeName,
                   routePrefix: routePrefix,
                   model: GetModel(),
                   batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

Please provide guideline.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload of `MapODataServiceRoute` that has both `defaultHandler` and `batchHandler` parameters. However, if you look at the [source code for the overload that takes an ODataBatchHandler](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/Extensions/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs#L425), you'll see that it is simply registering a separate batching route for the handler. You can simply copy that logic in to your own OData configuration code. For example:

```
var batchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
batchHandler.ODataRouteName = routeName;
config.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(routeName + "Batch", routePrefix + "/$batch", batchHandler);
```

And follow that with a call to the `MapODataServiceRoute` overload that takes the `defaultHandler` parameter.

Comment: I tried above code, but I got error

`<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:62673/Data/Master/$batch'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:62673/Data/Master/$batch'
</MessageDetail>
</Error>`

Comment: Oops. Looks like you have to register the batch handler first, then register the default handler. I've updated the answer appropriately.